# Dynamically change width to adjust div inside another div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a custom div with input text and two buttons inside it as shown below.
[image]

But when i resize the screen it becomes like this
[image]

Is there a way to avoid the two buttons to come down ? Instead it should remain inside the original div.

Here's the code i tried:

```css
.searchBar {
 background: #DDDDDD;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding: 10px;
 position: relative;
}

.search_field {
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius:4px ;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 width: 70%;height: 32px;
 position: relative;
 left: 60px;
 overflow: inherit;
}

.search_field input {
 width: 89%;
 padding: 0;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border:1px inset red;
}

.search_field input:focus {
 outline-color: transparent;
 outline-style: none;
}

.search_field button {
 border: none;
 background: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="searchBar" class="searchBar">
 <div class="search_field">                
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search" oninput="showSearchButtons()"/>
  <button id="btn1"  hidden="true" onclick="alert()"><img src="assets/images/search.png"></button>                    
  <button id="btn2" hidden="true" onclick="alert()"><img src="assets/images/saveBtn.png"></button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where is your CSS for the `button` elements? (apart from setting the border and background)

Comment: HI, The CSS for button is mentioned already

Comment: No it isn't. If your input element is 89%, how do you assume that your buttons - although fixed by the image width - will fit in the remaining 11%?

Comment: I'd also recommend adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the input so that the 89% width is inclusive of the padding and borders that you've got

Comment: @ somethinghere so, can i create another div and put these two buttons inside that and set the width to 11%? Will that help? @SamWillis thanks for the tip

Comment: I have posted an answer, and it comes down to using percentages as a fallback - they're not very nice for responsive layouts. SImply use `calc` to get the right width for your input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calc to calculate the width of your input element relative to your buttons:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Just make sure the width of your buttons is taken of the `100%`. In SASS it could look like this:

```
$buttons: 50px;
width: calc(100% - #{$buttons * 2});
```

Below is a simplified implementation. I still have the `%` values as a fallback for older browsers - but that's more a habit than necessity as every major browser supports calc, even IE9 and onward.

```css
input, button {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
input {
    width: 70%;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    padding: 10px;
}
button {
    /* Note that this width is equal to 100% 
    /* minus the percentage width of the input 
    /* divided by the amount of buttons. */
    width: 15%; 
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
/* This rule is just to make sure your images don't decide the buttons width */
button img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='search' />
<button><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></button>
<button><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Appreciate it. Will accept this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

```css
Please try this instead of your styles:

.searchBar{
 background: #DDDDDD;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding: 10px;
 position: relative;
}
.search_field {
 border-radius:4px ;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 position: relative;
 padding-right: 100px; /* You can change as button width */
}
.search_field input {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border: solid 1px #FF0000;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.search_field button {
 border: none;
 background: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}
.search_field button#btn1 {
 right: 50px; /* Change as your requirement */
}
.search_field button#btn2 {
 right: 0; /* Change as your requirement */
}
```